# Skip leading and trailing white space

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am using `regexp_split_to_array` to split a text in words by cutting of white space as following:

```
select regexp_split_to_array('  this   is    just    me   ', '\s+');
```

This gives:

```
{"",this,is,just,me,""}
```

I want to have:

```
{this,is,just,me}
```

Is there a way to remove the leading and trailing white space when applying `regexp_split_to_array`?

Comment: try: select regexp_split_to_array('  this   is    just    me   '.strip(), \s+');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the inverse approach: match any char(s) other than whitespace with `\S+` regex pattern:

```
select regexp_matches('  this   is    just    me   ', '\S+', 'g')
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/XWL18235). Note that `'g'` argument will enable multiple matching.

[image]

Use `unnest` on the regexp matches to expand an array to a set of rows if necessary.

Comment: This is a smart approach. This avoids having to process the input text twice, which is the case with `trim`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(TRIM('  this   is    just    me   '), '\s+');
```

`TRIM` with no parameters will [remove both leading and trailing whitespace](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trim` on the string before passing it to `regex_split_to_array` function:

```
select regexp_split_to_array(trim('  this   is    just    me   '), '\s+');
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others